# Define a measure in $\Bbb{R^k}$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

I'm studying Measure Theory. After reading my teacher's lecture notes, it is not clear for me the statement:

"In $\Bbb{R}^k$, It's impossible to define a $\sigma$ finite measure the satisfies all the following conditions:

1. $m(E)$ $\in$ [$0$,$\infty$] for every E (E is a subsets of $\Bbb{R}^K$)
2. $m$ is invariant under isometries
3. $m(R)=|R|$ (for all rectangles R in $\Bbb{R}^K$)

I don't know how to prove this statement :( Any help is appreciated

Comment: You mean it is a measure defined on the sigma algebra of all subsets of $\mathbb{R}^k$?

Comment: See Banach-Tarski paradox: the volume of the sphere (in $\Bbb R^3$) can be doubled by only rotating and shifting finitely many parts of it. If all these parts had a measure, $1=2$ would follow.

Comment: @LorenzoQuarisa yup

Comment: Since the Lebesgue measure satisfies 2, 3 and 1 for all Lebesgue-measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}^k$, any proof implies the existence of non-measurable sets, so you need the axiom of choice in some form

Comment: @LorenzoQuarisa I know lebesgue measure is an example. But can we prove the statement ?

Comment: The proof exists in many textbooks and the Wikipedia article on Banach-Tarski.  So there is no reason to repeat it here.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach–Tarski_paradox

Answer (score 2):

There's an easy way to prove this without appealing to Banach-Tarski. It relies on the following two facts:

- The Lebesgue measure is the unique measure on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb R^k)$ of $\mathbb R^k$ satisfying the latter two properties.
- The Lebesgue measure does not extend to a complete $\sigma$-algebra on the power set $\mathcal P(\mathbb R^k)$ that is translation invariant.

The first property is a standard measure theory result, and can be proved using the [Dynkin $\pi$-$\lambda$ lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_system#Dynkin's_%CF%80-%CE%BB_theorem) applied to successively larger balls. For the latter note that the [Vitali set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set) cannot be measurable which gives the case $k=1$ (the non-measurability proof provided on the wiki page will give you a contradiction). For general $k,$ one can apply the same argument to the product $V \times [0,1]^{k-1}$ where $V$ is the Vitali set.

Comment: The second bullet is not so simple. The Lebesgue measure can be extended to the complete $\sigma$-algebra under suitable set-theoretic assumptions (consistent with ZFC), but the measure cannot be translation-invariant (which the Vitali set shows). With that out of the way, for the first bullet, you can also use the uniqueness property of the Haar measure (this also tells you that even if you weaken 2. to only say that $m$ is translation invariant, and weaken 3. to only say this for one particular nontrivial rectangle, this is still impossible).

Comment: @tomasz The second point was a typo (I meant satisfying the given properties), so thanks for the correction. While the uniqueness of the Haar measure would certainly do it also however, I figured someone studying measure theory for the first time may not be familiar with that result.

Comment: Yeah, absolutely. I was just pointing out that you can use that to obtain a slightly sharper result.

Comment: Also, what Banach-Tarski *is* neccessary for is showing that there is no isometry-invariant *finitely* additive measure (but this is only true for $k>2$ --- in one and two dimensions,  we have the Banach means).